# Why do I pass the window object in to the module pattern?

Tags: javascript

Here is a self executing anonymous method.

It seems to be good practice to pass in window as global.  If window is available everywhere already why is this done?

```
(function (global) { 

 /* my code */ 

 global["someName"] = someObject; 

})(window);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It skips the code having to do a scope lookup since `global` is scoped inside the function.

---

Edit -- It's a performance optimization.  Scoping in javascript is limited to function scope.  `global` in this case is being defined within that scope, so when the code hits `global[...]` it looks at it's immediate scope (within the function) and finds `global` right away.  Without that it would then have to move up to the closure scope, which in this case is the global javascript namespace, and search that entire scope for `window`.

Comment: Yes.  You can think of `global` as a pointer to window, kind of like saying a nickname is faster than saying a person's legal name.

Comment: @Delnan - if you can make something better, why not do it?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Why waste time thinking of ways to do it "better" and implement them when they will never have any effect?

Comment: Different developers work at different scales.  Some developers write code that is run once a week, others write code that is run millions of times per day.  Depending on the scale, optimizations may or may not matter.  The heart of the pragmatic programmer is knowing what details are relevant to the code you're writing, at the scale you're writing it for, and focusing on those.

Comment: Also, both libraries I've taken the time to look at make this optimization - jQuery and Backbone

Answer (score 2):

The browser's JavaScript interpreter has to determine the scope of any variables it finds, starting at the most local scope and working its way outward. Using a function closure with `window` as the parameter `global` reduces the need to extend further up the scope chain to find `window`.

`window` *is* available everywhere, but using `global` the way it is in your example is more performant.