# Is there any catch/gotcha in this JavaScript boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a website with jQuery and organize code into several script files.

If I didn't get it wrong, there's a best practice of organizing your code like this boilerplate (which creates a separated scope and set the `undefined` value correctly):

```
(function($, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // code here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In my case, I will also rely on some external configuration outputted by some server-side script, say it is stored as global variable `site_config`. So currently my script boilerplate is:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    var document = window.document;
    var $ = window.jQuery;
    var config = window.site_config;

    // equivalent to $(document).ready(function() {...
    $(function() {
        // code here using `config`
    });
})(window);
```

So my question is: is there any catch/gotcha in this boilerplate?

Specifically:

1. is it OK to pass in `window` explicitly? (suppose the wrapper function is in global scope)
2. should I use `window.document` or `jQuery.document`? If both are wrong, how to reference correctly?

Comment: `window` is fine, as long as no one overwrote/shadowed the `window` object. Of course, in that case, one has much more serious problems. You could pass the `this` from the global scope instead of `window` as a `this` reference cannot be overwritten after entering the execution context.

Comment: There is no `jQuery.document`.

Comment: Can't you also simply add an extra parameter to your function and pass the site_config through that when calling it?

Comment: As your code is perfectly functional, this could be a better fit for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté great advice on using `this`, thank you!

Comment: @David I must have remembered it wrong. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it OK to pass in window explicitly?

It's OK, but unnecessary (see [Why do I pass the window object in to the module pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8174691/1048572)).

> should I use window.document or jQuery.document? If both are wrong, how to reference correctly?

`jQuery.document` is wrong, the `jQuery` function object has no such property. However, it would be fine to just use `document`, as it is a global and non-writable variable.